# How to get subplot to show two ploty plots?

Tags: r, plotly, subplot

I am trying to generate two simple plots of the same block side by side using subplot but only one of the plots is shown.

```
size = 50000
width = 4
x1 = 0
x2 = width
y1 = 0
y2 = size

p1 <- plot_ly(type='area',mode='none',x = c(x1,x2,x2,x1,x1),width = 500, height = 725,
          y = c(y1,y1,y2,y2,y1),
          fill = 'toself',
          fillcolor = 'rgb(233,87,62)')

x1 = 0
x2 = width
y1 = 0
y2 = size

p2 <- plot_ly(type='area',mode='none',x = c(x1,x2,x2,x1,x1),width = 500, height = 725,
         y = c(y1,y1,y2,y2,y1),
         fill = 'toself',
         fillcolor = 'rgb(233,87,62)')

subplot(p1,p2,nrows=1)
```

Comment: Maybe you want `type="scatter"`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To properly create a area chart with plotly, start with a scatter chart and then set mode to "lines".

Here is example with a better sample dataset:

```
library(plotly) 
p1 <- plot_ly(economics, type='scatter', x = ~date, y = ~uempmed, 
          name = 'Left chart',
          fill = 'tozeroy', 
          mode = 'lines', 
          fillcolor = 'rgb(233,87,62)', 
          line = list(color = 'rgb(233,87,62)'))

p2 <- plot_ly(economics, type='scatter', x = ~date, y = ~unemploy, 
              name = 'Right chart',
              fill = 'tozeroy', mode = 'lines', fillcolor = 'rgb(87,87,62)', 
              line = list(color = 'rgb(87,87,62)'))

subplot(p1, p2,  nrows = 1, margin = 0.05, widths =  c(0.6, 0.4))
```

[image]